# Power BI REST API returning 404 for dataset datasources, despite dataset and datasources existing

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-rest-api

I'm encountering an issue with the Power BI REST API while attempting to access datasources for a specific dataset using the endpoint `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets/{datasetId}/datasources.`

```
$reportdataSources = Get-PowerBIDataSource -DatasetId $dataSet -Scope Organization 
         $url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/$dataSet/datasources"
         $connectionDetails = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Get
```

Despite confirming the existence of both the dataset and its datasources, the API consistently returns a 404 error, with the following message:

```
{"error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
```

I've verified the following:

1. The dataset ID provided in the request exists in my Power BI environment.
2. The dataset has associated datasources, confirmed through alternate means.
3. My account has been assigned the role of Power Platform Administrator.

However, I'm using a Power BI free account license.

Could anyone shed light on why I might be receiving a 404 error despite the existence of the dataset and datasources? Could the type of Power BI license (in this case, a free account type) affect access to administrative endpoints?

Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

Reference article: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets-get-datasources-as-admin#code-try-0`

Answer (score 0):

`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets/{datasetId}` is for a dataset in **My workspace**.

Whereas I think you are needing:
`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}` is for a dataset in a workspace with **{groupId}**.

So you will need to know the DatasetID and the GroupID (workspace).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the endpoint provided gives 401 error, and reason i think is don't have access to workspace directly. I'm just admin but workspaces are not shared with me. The endpoint you have provided i think will work for the users who have access on workspace/dataset, in my case i don't have access, so have to rely on admin endpoint only that im using.. Please let me know if otherwise.. Also endpoint's documentation doesn't specify if it gets  data for myworkspaces only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/datasets-get-datasources-as-admin#code-try-0